# how to use keras h5 model in iOS (or Android) app

Tags: keras, coreml

I trained a model with keras retinanet 50, now I have an h5 file which works great when testing it with static images.

I would love to have it in an iOS (and/or Android) app but I fail at converting it to e.g. coreml:

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model) # => error occurs
coreml_model.save('my_model.mlmodel')
```

the error is

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-7-ba230c07a72c> in <module>()
      1 import coremltools
----> 2 coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
      3 # Saving the Core ML model to a file.
      4 coreml_model.save('my_model.mlmodel')

/home/jonas/projects/keras/keras-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.pyc in convert(model, input_names, output_names, image_input_names, is_bgr, red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias, gray_bias, image_scale, class_labels, predicted_feature_name, model_precision, predicted_probabilities_output, add_custom_layers, custom_conversion_functions)
    743                       predicted_probabilities_output,
    744                       add_custom_layers,
--> 745                       custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
    746 
    747     return _MLModel(spec)

/home/jonas/projects/keras/keras-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.pyc in convertToSpec(model, input_names, output_names, image_input_names, is_bgr, red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias, gray_bias, image_scale, class_labels, predicted_feature_name, model_precision, predicted_probabilities_output, add_custom_layers, custom_conversion_functions, custom_objects)
    541                                            add_custom_layers=add_custom_layers,
    542                                            custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions,
--> 543                                            custom_objects=custom_objects)
    544     else:
    545         raise RuntimeError(

/home/jonas/projects/keras/keras-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.pyc in _convert(model, input_names, output_names, image_input_names, is_bgr, red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias, gray_bias, image_scale, class_labels, predicted_feature_name, predicted_probabilities_output, add_custom_layers, custom_conversion_functions, custom_objects)
    185 
    186     # Check valid versions
--> 187     _check_unsupported_layers(model, add_custom_layers)
    188 
    189     # Build network graph to represent Keras model

/home/jonas/projects/keras/keras-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.pyc in _check_unsupported_layers(model, add_custom_layers)
     98         else:
     99             if type(layer) not in _KERAS_LAYER_REGISTRY:
--> 100                 raise ValueError("Keras layer '%s' not supported. " % str(type(layer)))
    101             if isinstance(layer, _keras.layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed):
    102                 if type(layer.layer) not in _KERAS_LAYER_REGISTRY:

ValueError: Keras layer '<class 'keras_resnet.layers._batch_normalization.BatchNormalization'>' not supported.
```

I also tried exporting weight and architecture (json) and the load the model again, but the error stays the same.

According to the last answer (https://www.quora.com/Does-Residual-Learning-work-without-batch-normalization) I understand that batchnormalization is only used for training, so is there a way to convert it into coreml?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment of Matthjis I tried the following:

```
import keras

class BatchNormalization(keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
    """
    Identical to keras.layers.BatchNormalization, but adds the option to freeze parameters.
    """
    def __init__(self, freeze, *args, **kwargs):
        print("here we are")
        self.freeze = freeze
        super(BatchNormalization, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # set to non-trainable if freeze is true
        self.trainable = not self.freeze

    def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # return super.call, but set training
        print("here we are")
        return super(BatchNormalization, self).call(training=(not self.freeze), *args, **kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        print("here we are")
        config = super(BatchNormalization, self).get_config()
        config.update({'freeze': self.freeze})
        return config
```

and then

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, custom_conversion_functions={"BatchNormalization": BatchNormalization})
```

but I still get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

Batch Normalization is also used during inference and Core ML does support it.

However, `keras_resnet.layers._batch_normalization.BatchNormalization` is not the standard BatchNormalization layer from Keras, so coremltools does not understand how to handle it.

The good news: this new BatchNormalization layer extends the Keras standard BatchNormalization layer, so it's possible to make your model work with Core ML.  https://github.com/broadinstitute/keras-resnet/blob/master/keras_resnet/layers/_batch_normalization.py

Three options:

1. You can tell coremltools this is a custom layer and in the function that handles the custom layer you then return a `BatchnormLayerParams` object. More info on how to deal with custom layers in coremltools: http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/
2. You can replace the `keras_resnet.layers._batch_normalization.BatchNormalization` layers in the model with `keras.layers.BatchNormalization` layers and then run coremltools as usual.
3. Find out where your coremltools is installed, then in **_keras2_converter.py**, add a line for keras_resnet.layers._batch_normalization.BatchNormalization, like so:

   ```
   keras_resnet.layers._batch_normalization.BatchNormalization:  _layers2.convert_batchnorm,
   ```

   just like here: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/052446a0b8925a019096cdc5529b7793d1e9bf30/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py#L49

   You'll also have to import `keras_resnet` into this file otherwise coremltools won't be able to find this module. Then run coremltools as usual.

Comment: thanks! I try option 1) - so I change `coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)` to `coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, custom_conversion_functions={"BatchNormalization": ...})`, right? But I don't get exactly what I have to put as value, i.e. how that def function should look like which I need to put in there...

Comment: That's not how `custom_conversion_functions` works. You have to write a function that takes this custom BatchNormalization layer and converts it into something Core ML understands. I added an option 3 to my answer that is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: thanks, seems as if I'm one step further: `Keras layer '<class 'keras_retinanet.layers._misc.UpsampleLike'>' not supported.` Would be really great if you could help me with this problems, I will add a bounty as soon as I can and reward it to you!

Comment: That looks like you'll need to write a conversion function for. Core ML does have upsampling layers but coremltools does not know that `keras_retinanet.layers._misc.UpsampleLike` is an upsampling layer.